# Quaternion.Lerp not even moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to lerp rotation to `new Quaternion(0,0,0,0);` but it seems like not animating to desired rotation at all... It just stop at where it is...

What I tried were those three on below

`RectTransform rectTransformComponent = this.transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rectTransformComponent.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(rectTransformComponent.localRotation, new Quaternion(0,0,0,0), 0.1f);`

and

`this.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.localRotation, new Quaternion(0,0,0,0), 0.1f);`

and

`this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(this.transform.rotation, new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0), 0.1f);`

I'm using RectTransform for this object. It was working without lerping. It's in   the Update() so it will be looped every frame. I tried to bring up the speed for lerp but no luck...

Does someone have any idea what is going on??

`this.transform.localRotation = new Quaternion(0,0,0,0)    //This works`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An all-zero quaternion (`new Quaternion(0,0,0,0)`) is an invalid rotation. `Quaternion.Lerp` doesn't know how to interpolate to an invalid rotation.

To rotate to an Euler rotation of x=0,y=0,z=0, then you should instead use `Quaternion.identity` (which is equivalent to `new Quaternion(0,0,0,1)`).